# Java - JTextField fills all frame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextfield

I am trying to achieve a very simple task: To make a JTextField that doesn't fill all screen. Currently I see this possible only with setMaximumSize, is there any other way? Here's my code:

```
JFrame window = new JFrame();
window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
Dimension screenSize = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
window.setSize(screenSize.width / 2, screenSize.height / 2);
window.setLocation(screenSize.width / 4, screenSize.height / 4);
window.setResizable(false);
JPanel pane = new JPanel();
pane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pane, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
pane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
pane.add(new JTextField(10));
window.setContentPane(pane);
```

Comment: Find a tutorial about layout managers.

Comment: The default layout manager for a JPanel is a FlowLayout. Just us the FlowLayout instead of the BoxLayout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from [`BoxLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html):

> For a top-to-bottom box layout, the preferred width of the container is that of the maximum preferred width of the children. **If the container is forced to be wider than that, `BoxLayout` attempts to size the width of each component to that of the container's width** (minus insets). If the maximum size of a component is smaller than the width of the container, then X alignment comes into play.

(emphasis mine). So your option with `BoxLayout` is, as you mentioned, to set the maximum size (and then handle the alignment if needed):

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
textField.setMaximumSize(textField.getPreferredSize());
textField.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT); // If needed
```

Otherwise, you will have to use a different [`LayoutManager`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html). A lot of things work. For starters, just remove the line

```
pane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pane, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
```

to use the default `FlowLayout`.

Note that if you place more components into the frame, this issue can "fix itself" since other components might be resized instead.

Answer (score 0):

use `GridBagLayout` this will give you a way to put constraints in each component of your screen.